# Best way to read/edit/add to the googlecode wiki offline

Tags: project-management, collaboration, google-code, project-hosting

I finally after too much of pondering started my project on googlecode. One of the best features I liked about googlecode was the revision control for wiki, where I can add/edit the wiki pages locally offline and then commit/push later.

I have pulled the wiki to my local repository, is there any good googlecode-wiki-toolbar-attached editor for googlecode wiki, as from my knowledge evey wiki has its own syntax for writing.

Or if someone is also using a local repository for wiki.code.google, what practice are they following for writing the document for online collaborations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of googling, I think the only way is

download the wiki-repository, and edit pages manually through Vim or any text editor following the wikiSyntax. 
Then do an

> hg commit / hg add -- based on if u edited or added a file.

and then,

> hg push

to upload your files to the main wiki

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have saved the whole wiki, can't you open that up in your browser and just edit it like any other Wiki?

Comment: No it doesnt work, the browser doesnot provide any edit/add system, unless i will have the wiki-engine running on my localhost.